# Copying animation and sequence information between powerpoint shapes

Tags: vba, animation, powerpoint, shapes, timeline

I'm trying to replace all shape objects on the slide (pictures) with shape objects of another type (rectangular shape). I can delete old object and create new, but i will loose all animation information and sequence order. Is it possible to store animation information and order in timeline, and copy it to the new shape object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, i have found a solution myself, hope someone could find it useful. So, it is not necessary to copy animation information from old shape to a new one, just cycle through sequence's items and replace the shape object refrence to the new shape. Like this:

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim shp1 As Shape 'old shape
Set shp1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(3)

Dim shp2 As Shape 'new shape
Set shp2 = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddPicture("c:\imgres2.jpg", msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0) 'it is important to create new shape before cycling through existing ones.
For i = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).TimeLine.MainSequence.count To 1 Step -1
    'using "is" opeartor to compare refrences
    If shp1 Is ActivePresentation.Slides(1).TimeLine.MainSequence.Item(i).Shape Then
        ActivePresentation.Slides(1).TimeLine.MainSequence.Item(i).Shape = shp2
    End If
Next i
shp1.Delete 'delete the old shape
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this code to copy the animation into new added shape:

```
Sub PasteAnimationBehaviours()

Dim SHP As Shape 'for existing shape
Set SHP = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1)
    SHP.PickupAnimation


Dim newSHP As Shape 'pasting to new shape
Set newSHP = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 100, 100, 100, 100)
    newSHP.ApplyAnimation

End Sub
```

**Added after comment:** If you only need to replace type of shape try to use something like this:

```
Sub ShapeSubstition()

Dim SHP As Shape 'for existing shape
'test for 1st shape in 1st slide
Set SHP = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1) 

SHP.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRectangle 'to rectangle
SHP.AutoShapeType = msoShapeOval   'to oval
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks you for an answer! But it partially solves the problem, but new shape's animation is added to the end of the sequence timeline. How can i move new shape's animation to the specified position?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is probably easier to just use the "Animation Painter" command button to copy the animations and apply them to another object. The Animation Painter functions in the same way as the Format Painter. After you have copied the desired animations, you can reorder the individual animations using the Animation Pane.

Answer (score 0):

This code shows how to copy effects from one shape to another. Select a shape before running routine "SetSourceShape" and select one or more shapes before running "PaintEffects".

```
Option Explicit
' resources:
' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa168134(v=office.11).aspx
' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa168135(office.11).aspx
' http://skp.mvps.org/ppttimeline1.htm

' uses functions from:
' https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-copy-paste-animation-effect-in-powerpoint/c0f255c0-167a-4a12-ae37-1e713ee1d8df

Public MySourceShapeId As Long
Public MySourceSlideIndex As Long  ' need this with shape id for unique selection

Sub SetSourceShape()  ' sets source shape id value if successfull
Dim oShp As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim myShp As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim oSld As Slide
Dim oEffect As Effect
Dim HowMany As Long
Dim FoundEffect As Boolean
HowMany = 0          ' default value for nothing selected
MySourceShapeId = 0  ' default value for nothing available to copy
MySourceSlideIndex = 0
FoundEffect = False  ' default value unless selected shape has any effect(s)
On Error Resume Next ' handles error when nothing is selected
HowMany = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count
On Error GoTo 0      ' restore normal error handling
If HowMany = 0 Then
  MsgBox "Nothing is selected"
Else
  If HowMany = 1 Then
    Set oShp = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1) ' selection on a single slide
    For Each oEffect In ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1).TimeLine.MainSequence
      If oEffect.Shape.Id = oShp.Id Then
        MySourceShapeId = oShp.Id
        MySourceSlideIndex = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1).SlideIndex
        FoundEffect = True
      End If
    Next
    If FoundEffect Then
      MsgBox "Source is selected, Slide: " & MySourceSlideIndex & ", ShapeID: " & MySourceShapeId
    Else
      MsgBox "Selected item has no effect(s)"
    End If
  Else
    MsgBox "Select only one item"
  End If
End If
End Sub

Sub PaintEffects()
Dim oShp As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim oEffect As Effect
Dim HowMany As Long
Dim msg As String
HowMany = 0          ' default value for nothing selected
If MySourceShapeId = 0 Then
  MsgBox "No source is selected"
  Exit Sub
End If
On Error Resume Next ' handles error when nothing is selected
HowMany = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count
On Error GoTo 0      ' restore normal error handling
If HowMany = 0 Then
  MsgBox "Nothing is selected to paint"
Else
  ' make sure source is not in this selection
  If ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1).SlideIndex = MySourceSlideIndex Then ' check shapes
    For Each oShp In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
      If oShp.Id = MySourceShapeId Then ' complain
        MsgBox "Target selection must not include source item"
        Exit Sub
      End If
    Next
  End If
  
  ' OK, proceed
  For Each oShp In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    For Each oEffect In ActivePresentation.Slides(MySourceSlideIndex).TimeLine.MainSequence
      If oEffect.Shape.Id = MySourceShapeId Then
        Call TransferEffects(oEffect, ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1), oShp)
      End If
    Next
  Next
End If
End Sub

Sub TransferEffects(oEffectA As PowerPoint.Effect, oSlide As Slide, oShape As PowerPoint.Shape)
Dim oEffectB As Effect
Dim IsMotion As Boolean

Set oEffectB = oSlide.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(oShape, oEffectA.EffectType)
DoEvents
On Error Resume Next
oEffectB.EffectParameters.Amount = oEffectA.EffectParameters.Amount
If Err.Number = 0 Then
  Select Case oEffectA.EffectParameters.Color2.Type
    Case Is = msoColorTypeScheme
      oEffectB.EffectParameters.Color2.SchemeColor = oEffectA.EffectParameters.Color2.SchemeColor
    Case Is = msoColorTypeRGB
      oEffectB.EffectParameters.Color2.RGB = oEffectA.EffectParameters.Color2.RGB
  End Select
End If

oEffectB.EffectParameters.Direction = oEffectA.EffectParameters.Direction
oEffectB.EffectParameters.FontName = oEffectA.EffectParameters.FontName

If oEffectA.EffectType <> msoAnimEffectGrowShrink Then
  oEffectB.EffectParameters.Size = oEffectA.EffectParameters.Size
Else
  oEffectB.Behaviors(1).ScaleEffect.ByX = oEffectA.Behaviors(1).ScaleEffect.ByX
  oEffectB.Behaviors(1).ScaleEffect.ByY = oEffectA.Behaviors(1).ScaleEffect.ByY
End If

oEffectB.Timing.Duration = oEffectA.Timing.Duration
oEffectB.Timing.Accelerate = oEffectA.Timing.Accelerate
oEffectB.Timing.AutoReverse = oEffectA.Timing.AutoReverse
oEffectB.Timing.Decelerate = oEffectA.Timing.Decelerate
oEffectB.Timing.Restart = oEffectA.Timing.Restart
oEffectB.Timing.RewindAtEnd = oEffectA.Timing.RewindAtEnd
oEffectB.Timing.SmoothStart = oEffectA.Timing.SmoothStart
oEffectB.Timing.SmoothEnd = oEffectA.Timing.SmoothEnd
oEffectB.Exit = oEffectA.Exit
oEffectB.Timing.TriggerType = oEffectA.Timing.TriggerType
oEffectB.Timing.TriggerDelayTime = oEffectA.Timing.TriggerDelayTime
oEffectB.Timing.RepeatCount = oEffectA.Timing.RepeatCount
oEffectB.Timing.RepeatDuration = oEffectA.Timing.RepeatDuration
oEffectB.Timing.Speed = oEffectA.Timing.Speed

With oSlide.TimeLine.MainSequence
  If oEffectA.Shape.HasTextFrame Then
    Call .ConvertToAnimateBackground(oEffectB, oEffectA.EffectInformation.AnimateBackground)
  Else
    Call .ConvertToAnimateBackground(oEffectB, True)
  End If
  
  Select Case oEffectA.EffectInformation.AfterEffect
    Case 2 ' Hide
      Call .ConvertToAfterEffect(oEffectB, oEffectA.EffectInformation.AfterEffect)
    Case 1 ' Dim
      Call .ConvertToAfterEffect(oEffectB, oEffectA.EffectInformation.AfterEffect, oEffectA.EffectInformation.Dim)
    Case 3 ' Hide on click
      Call .ConvertToAfterEffect(oEffectB, oEffectA.EffectInformation.AfterEffect)
  End Select
  
  Call .ConvertToAnimateInReverse(oEffectB, oEffectA.EffectInformation.AnimateTextInReverse)
  Call .ConvertToTextUnitEffect(oEffectB, oEffectA.EffectInformation.TextUnitEffect)
End With

Err.Clear
oEffectB.EffectParameters.Relative = oEffectA.EffectParameters.Relative
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    IsMotion = False
Else
    IsMotion = True
End If

If IsMotion Then
  oEffectB.Behaviors(1).MotionEffect.Path = oEffectA.Behaviors(1).MotionEffect.Path
  On Error GoTo 0
  If Sgn(Val(oEffectA.Behaviors(1).Timing.Speed)) = -1 Then
  oEffectB.Behaviors(1).MotionEffect.Path = Left(oEffectA.Behaviors(1).MotionEffect.Path, 1) & " " & ReversePathInfo(Trim(Mid(oEffectA.Behaviors(1).MotionEffect.Path, 2)))
  End If
End If

Exit Sub
errHandler:

If MsgBox(Err.Number & " " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "Do you wish to continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "APP_NAME") = vbYes Then
  Resume Next
End If

End Sub


Function ReversePathInfo(sPath As String) As String
Dim sItems() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim sPositions() As String
Dim sReversedPath As String
Dim sClosedPath As String

If Not IsNumeric(Right(sPath, 1)) Then
  sClosedPath = Right(sPath, 1)
  sPath = Left(sPath, Len(sPath) - 1)
End If

sPath = Replace(sPath, "  ", "~")
sItems = Split(sPath, "~")
ReDim sPositions(0 To UBound(sItems))

For i = LBound(sItems) To UBound(sItems)
  If Left(sItems(i), 1) = "L" Then sPositions(i) = "L"
  If Left(sItems(i), 1) = "C" Then sPositions(i) = "C"
  If Left(sItems(i), 1) = "c" Then sPositions(i) = "c"
  If Left(sItems(i), 1) = "l" Then sPositions(i) = "l"
Next i

For i = LBound(sPositions) To UBound(sPositions)
  If LCase(sPositions(i)) = "c" Then
    sPositions(i + 2) = sPositions(i)
    sPositions(i) = ""
    i = i + 2
  End If
Next i

For i = UBound(sItems) To LBound(sItems) Step -1
  Select Case Left(sItems(i), 1)
    Case "L", "C", "c", "l"
      sItems(i) = Trim(Mid(sItems(i), 2))
  End Select
  sReversedPath = sReversedPath & sItems(i) & "  " & sPositions(i) & IIf(sPositions(i) <> "", " ", "")
Next i

ReversePathInfo = Trim(sReversedPath) & IIf(sClosedPath = "", "", "  " & sClosedPath)
End Function
```