# Copy animation effects from one shape to other

Tags: vba, animation, powerpoint, shapes

I am trying to copy animation effects from one shape to other.

The motion path & fade effects throw error:

> Method/data member not found.

Is there any other way to apply animation effects of one shape to other by VBA code, or any other libraries?

```vb
Sub CopyAnimationsToSelectedShape1()
    Dim sourceShape As shape
    Dim targetShape As shape
    Dim sourceAnim As AnimationSettings
    Dim targetAnim As AnimationSettings

    ' Set the source shape
    Set sourceShape = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("SourceShape") ' Replace with your source shape name

    ' Check if the source shape can be animated
    If sourceShape.HasTextFrame Then
        Set sourceAnim = sourceShape.AnimationSettings

        ' Check if exactly one shape is selected
        If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionShapes And ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count = 1 Then
            Set targetShape = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
            Set targetAnim = targetShape.AnimationSettings

            ' Copy animation settings from the source to the target
            If sourceAnim.Animate = msoTrue Then
                targetAnim.Animate = msoTrue
                targetAnim.EntryEffect = sourceAnim.EntryEffect
                targetAnim.AdvanceMode = sourceAnim.AdvanceMode
                targetAnim.AdvanceTime = sourceAnim.AdvanceTime
                targetAnim.AfterEffect = sourceAnim.AfterEffect
                targetAnim.AnimationOrder = sourceAnim.AnimationOrder
                targetAnim.AnimateBackground = sourceAnim.AnimateBackground
                targetAnim.AnimateTextInReverse = sourceAnim.AnimateTextInReverse
                targetAnim.effectType = msoAnimEffectFade
                
                If sourceAnim.HasMotionPath Then
                    Set targetAnim.MotionEffect = sourceAnim.MotionEffect
                End If

            End If

            MsgBox "Animation settings copied from source to selected shape."
        Else
            MsgBox "Select one shape as the target."
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "The source shape must have a text frame and animations."
    End If
    
    ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("SourceShape").Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73095536/4717755) for some insight into how to copy animations? My guess is that you are trying to access a method/property of an object that has not yet been set, so you have to test the object for the existance of the property first and respond appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, copying all animation properties can be complex but you can use the TimeLine object for copying the motion paths. Try this code.

```
    Dim srcShape As Shape
    Dim tgtShape As Shape
    Dim srcSlide As Slide
    Dim tgtSlide As Slide

    ' Validate and get target shape
    Set tgtShape = ValidateAndGetTargetShape()
    If tgtShape Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    ' Validate and get source shape
    Set srcShape = ValidateAndGetSourceShape(srcSlide)
    If srcShape Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    ' Set slides
    Set srcSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex)
    Set tgtSlide = srcSlide

    ' Copy Animations
    CopyAnimations srcSlide, srcShape, tgtSlide, tgtShape

    MsgBox "Animation settings copied from source to selected shape.", vbInformation, "Success"
End Sub

Function ValidateAndGetTargetShape() As Shape
    ' Check for selection
    If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionNone Then
        MsgBox "No shape selected. Select one shape as the target.", vbExclamation, "Error"
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Check if exactly one shape is selected
    If Not ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionShapes Or Not ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Select exactly one shape as the target.", vbExclamation, "Error"
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Return target shape
    Set ValidateAndGetTargetShape = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
End Function

Function ValidateAndGetSourceShape(srcSlide As Slide) As Shape
    Dim srcShapeName As String
    Dim srcShape As Shape
    
    ' Ask user to set the source shape
    srcShapeName = InputBox("Enter the name of the source shape:", "Set Source Shape")
    If srcShapeName = "" Then Exit Function

    ' Check if the source shape exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Set srcShape = srcSlide.Shapes(srcShapeName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If srcShape Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The source shape was not found.", vbExclamation, "Error"
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Check if source shape has a text frame
    If Not srcShape.HasTextFrame Then
        MsgBox "The source shape must have a text frame.", vbExclamation, "Error"
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Return source shape
    Set ValidateAndGetSourceShape = srcShape
End Function

Sub CopyAnimations(ByRef srcSlide As Slide, ByRef srcShape As Shape, ByRef tgtSlide As Slide, ByRef tgtShape As Shape)
    Dim srcEffect As Effect
    Dim tgtEffect As Effect
    Dim i As Integer
    
    For i = 1 To srcSlide.TimeLine.MainSequence.Count
        Set srcEffect = srcSlide.TimeLine.MainSequence.Item(i)
        If srcEffect.Shape.Name = srcShape.Name Then
            Set tgtEffect = tgtSlide.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(Shape:=tgtShape, _
                                    effectId:=srcEffect.EffectType, _
                                    trigger:=msoAnimTriggerAfterPrevious, Index:=i)
            tgtEffect.Timing.Duration = srcEffect.Timing.Duration
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Kim, its not copying motion sequence, but its copying animation whic is not in sourceshape, i updated code  to include Sourceshape in code, the animation on source shape is motion path, but after i run code, animation copied is blink